# libjpeg not exact pixel values even with quality of 100

Tags: colors, jpeg, rgb, grayscale, libjpeg-turbo

I am writing a program to read some text files and write it to a JPEG file using [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/). When I set the quality to 100 (with`jpeg_set_quality`), there is actually no quality degradation in grayscale. However, when I move to RGB, even with a quality of 100, there seems to be compression.

When I give this input to convert to a grayscale JPEG image it works nicely and gives me a clean JPEG image:

```
0  0  0 0 0
0  0  0 0 0
0  0  0 0 0
0 255 0 0 0
255 0 0 0 0
```

The (horizontally flipped) output is:

[image: grayscale]

Now when I assume that array was the Red color, and use the following two arrays for the Green and Blue colors respectively:

```
0 0  0  0 0
0 0  0  0 0
0 0 255 0 0
0 0  0  0 0
0 0  0  0 0


0 0 0  0 255
0 0 0 255 0
0 0 0  0  0
0 0 0  0  0
0 0 0  0  0
```

This is the color output I get:

[image: RGB]

While only 5 input pixels have any color value, the surrouding pixels have also gotten a value when converted to color. For both the grayscale image and RGB image the quality was set to 100.

I wanted to see what is causing this and how I can fix it so the colors are also only used for the pixels that actually have an input value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors from the RGB->YCbCr conversion. That is impossible to avoid in the large because there is not a 1:1 mapping between the two color spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is easy - just don't use jpeg. Png is a better choice for your use case.

What you are seeing is result of how jpeg compression works, there is such a thing as "lossless jpeg" but its really a completely different file format that isn't well supported.

Comment: Besides RGB, I also need CMYK and so I can't use PNG. I don't understand how in grayscale there is no compression but in color there is!?!